# Dynamic selectInput in shiny

Tags: r, user-interface, select, shiny, reactive-programming

I want to have a shiny app which the `ui` dinamically get updated.
As an example my dataset looks like :

```
lookup_table = structure(list(var = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                3L), .Label = c("var1", "var2", "var3"), class = "factor"), sub_var = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                  1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
                                                                                                                                  6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("var11", "var12", "var13", 
                                                                                                                                                                          "var21", "var22", "var31", "var32", "var33"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                -24L))
```

In the `ui` function I would like to have `selectInput` functions as many as 'length(unique(lookup_table$var))'

and the choices for these dropdowns will be the `unique(lookup_table$var)`.
the second set of dropdown should get their values from `lookup_table$sub_var` based on user selection in first set of dropdowns.

My sample app looks like the following but the second set of dropdowns are not updating !

```
    library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  #sidebarPanel(uiOutput('select_value')),
  mainPanel(uiOutput('input_value'),
            uiOutput('doc_name'))

)

server <- function(input , output){

  descriptive_data <- data.frame(unique(lookup_table$var))

  turb = as.character(unique(lookup_table[,1]))


  output$input_value <- renderUI({
    var_name <- as.character(unique(lookup_table$var))
    if (!is.null(var_name)) {
      # lapply will return a list
      lapply(1:length(var_name), function(k) { 
        selectInput(paste0("var", k), 
                     'first selection ',turb )
      })
    }
  })

  main2 <- reactive({
    var_name <- as.character(unique(lookup_table$var))
    sub_var=lapply(1:length(var_name), function(k) { 
      as.character(unique(filter(lookup_table,var == paste0("input$var",k))[,2]))
    })

    result = list(sub_var = sub_var)
    return(result)

  })

  output$doc_name <- renderUI({
    var_name <- as.character(unique(lookup_table$var))
    if (!is.null(var_name)) {
      # lapply will return a list
      lapply(1:length(var_name), function(k) { 
        selectInput(paste0("doc", k), 
                   'sub_var', main2()$sub_var[[k]] )
      })
    }
  })  


}

shinyApp(ui = ui , server = server)
```

I don't know what ddi I miss here !